# Passing a variable from main into a public class function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering how in this situation I can pass a variable from main into a public class function. In this situation the health variable doesn't change at all even though it should. Here's my code:

```
class PlayerCharacter
{
public:
    void SetHealth(int Health)
{
    m_health = Health;
}
int GetHealth()
{
    return m_health;
}
private:
int m_health;
int m_maxhealth;
};


int main()
{
    PlayerCharacter PC;
    bool playing = true;
    int Choice;
    int v1;
    int v2;
    while (playing)
    {
        PrintMainMenu();
        cout << "Set Health And Max Health" << endl;
        cin >> Choice;
        v1 = Choice;
        cin >> Choice;
        v2 = Choice;
        PC.SetHealth(v1);
        PC.SetMaxHealth(v2);

        system("CLS");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks.

edit: [All of my code](https://pastebin.com/xW6sJhpk)

Comment: The health value still doesn't get affected.

Comment: how do you know its not changing? it looks like JeJo's example reads it in as `8` and prints it back out as `8` just fine...

Comment: Why do you have `Choice`? What's wrong with `cin >> v1;` then `cin >> v2;`  (where you should actually check `if (!(cin >> v1)) { /* handle error */ }`, etc.. to *validate your input*)

Comment: I know it isn't changing because the main menu has a loop to update if the health value changes. The main goal is for the health to increase after the player rests.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: This would require an [mcve]. Have you used a debugger to check what’s happening actually to see if the issue is in this part of the code or elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

From your code link, your `PrintMainMenu()` function is creating an entirely new `Character` each time. It has no relation to the one being edited in `main()`.

You should change it to accept a `Character` as a reference and use that to print your stats:

```
void PrintMainMenu(Character& PC) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using getline (cin, input) instead of cin>> as reading directly with cin is not type safe and as far as I know, it does not remove newline character. Also, it does not perform length check. So it has been some time not to use C++ but if I remember correctly getline works better.

```
getline (cin, Choice);
```

Answer (score 0):

In function `void PrintMainMenu()` you are creating a new Character.
You need to pass a reference on your Character from main into this function.